# Storing data from one array into two others not working

Tags: c++

I posted in an earlier question about having two different types of data values to read out from a txt file like so :

Titanic

600788188

Star Wars

460998007

I figured out using getline all the data could be stored into one string array but I needed them to be separate for a later operation so I tried to create an algorithm that would seperate the words from the numbers like this:

```
while(getline(inMovie, line[x]))
    {



        if((x % 2) == 0)
        {

            line[x] = title[c];
            c++;
        }
        else 
        {
            line[x] = income[r];
            r++;
        }


        x++;
    }
```

But for some reason, this isn't working either.

Comment: aren't you assigning in opposite direction you want to?

Comment: "*But for some reason, this isn't working either.*": What does that mean? Please be precise.

Comment: Your assignments are backwards. Unrelated, I don't see the sense in a separate `lines` array anyway.  a single temp and a few counters (*outside* the loop) should do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
while(getline(inMovie, line))
    {



        if((x % 2) == 0)
        {

            title[c] = line;
            c++;

        }
        else 
        {
            income[r] = stoi(line);
            r++;

        }

        x++;
    }
```

Really really stupid on my part and is a great example of the effects of flu brain.

Comment: There is probably no need for `line` to be an array. give something like `while(getline(inMovie, title[x]) && getline(inMovie, tempincome)) { income[x] = stoi(tempincome); x++; }` a try.

Comment: Note: I should warn you that if `c` or `r` is greater than or equal to the size of those arrays, it could overrun the buffer. That would probably result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Or an attack by ninja assassins. Undefined behaviour is undefined. Who knows what'll happen.